# No coinciden los tipos de datos en la expresión

Tags: ms-access, vb

Tengo un formulario el cual se encarga de filtrar los datos de un subformulario. 
Tiene los siguientes datos: Matricula (Número), Fecha, Proyecto (Texto), Descripción (Texto).

En el formulario para filtrar, se requiere una opción para filtrar los campos Matricula, Fecha y Proyecto. Se debería filtrar solo uno, como los 3 a la vez. Esto es lo que funciona regular. 
Con el código actual que tengo me permite filtrar tanto solos como a la vez los campos Matricula y Fecha. El problema está en el campo Proyecto, que es el que da el error. Pero no sé qué estoy haciendo mal, y por más que pruebe distintos códigos, me sigue saliendo el mismo fallo.

Aquí el código:

```
Private Sub BtnFiltro_Click()

Dim FiltroFecha As String
Dim FiltroMatricula As String
Dim FiltroProyecto As String
Dim FiltroTotal As String

    If Not IsNull(Me.txtMatricula) And Me.txtMatricula <> "" Then
        FiltroMatricula = "MATRICULA =" & Me.txtMatricula
    Else
        FiltroMatricula = ""
    End If

    If Not IsNull(Me.txtProyecto) And Me.txtProyecto <> "" Then
        FiltroProyecto = "PROYECTO =" & Me.txtProyecto
    Else
        FiltroProyecto = ""
    End If

    If IsNull(Me.FechaDesde) And IsNull(Me.FechaHasta) Then
        FiltroFecha = ""
    Else
        FiltroFecha = "FECHA BETWEEN #" & Format(Nz(Me.FechaDesde, #1/1/2019#), "dd/mm/yyyy") & _
                    "# AND #" & Format(Nz(Me.FechaHasta, #12/31/2050#), "dd/mm/yyyy") & "#"
    End If

    If FiltroMatricula <> "" Then
        If FiltroTotal <> "" Then
            FiltroTotal = FiltroTotal & " AND " & FiltroMatricula
        Else
            FiltroTotal = FiltroMatricula
        End If
    End If

    If FiltroProyecto <> "" Then
        If FiltroTotal <> "" Then
            FiltroTotal = FiltroTotal & " AND " & FiltroProyecto
        Else
            FiltroTotal = FiltroProyecto
        End If
    End If

    If FiltroFecha <> "" Then
        If FiltroTotal <> "" Then
            FiltroTotal = FiltroTotal & " AND " & FiltroFecha
        Else
            FiltroTotal = FiltroFecha
        End If
    End If

    Debug.Print FiltroTotal

    If FiltroTotal <> "" Then
        Me.Subformulario.Form.Filter = FiltroTotal
        Me.Subformulario.Form.FilterOn = True
    Else
        Me.Subformulario.Form.FilterOn = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error de no coincide el tipo de datos es el que nos indica la resolución del error. Tienes un campo de texto (Proyecto) y debes montar una sentencia sql que filtre por ese texto (ya lo haces), pero con la sintaxis correcta.

Para que la sintaxis sea correcta debes rodear el texto (antes y después) buscado por comillas simples.

```
FiltroProyecto = "PROYECTO = '" & Me.txtProyecto & "'"
```